# Calculating line integral of $y\,dx+z\,dy+x\,dz$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate the integral $$\int_{\gamma} y\,dx+z\,dy+x\,dz $$ when $$\gamma=\{(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2, x+y+z=0\}$$

I tried to isolate $z$ and to replace it in the sphere but I stucked in the parametric track.

thank you!

Comment: Do you know Stokes' theorem?

Comment: yes. but I dont know if this is the way

Comment: please, can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exercise is best to be tackled using Stokes' theorem: $$\mathcal{F}=\oint_\gamma ydx+zdy+xdz=\oint_\gamma \left<y,z,x \right>\cdot d\vec{r}=\iint_S \nabla\times\left<y,z,x \right>\cdot\vec{n}ds,$$ where $\gamma$ is the boundary of $S$ and $\vec{n}=\vec{n}(x,y,z)$ is the unit normal field oriented so that while traversing the countour $\gamma$ the surface $S$ remains on the left side.

Since we have some freedom in choosing $S$, let's take $S$ to be the circle whose boundary is $\gamma$. In this case, $\vec{n}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\left<1,1,1\right>$. We notice that $\nabla\times\left<y,z,x \right>=-\left<1,1,1\right>$ and $\nabla\times\left<y,z,x \right>\cdot\vec{n}=\pm\sqrt{3}$ then $$\mathcal{F}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\iint_SdS=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}A(S)=\pm\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{3}}.$$

**Notes:** the direction of the contour $\gamma$ was not specified. It will affect the sign of the the integral, hence we have $\pm$ in the final answer. $A(S)=\pi a^2$ denotes the area of the circle that lies in the intersection of the sphere and the plane. Since the plane passes through the center of the sphere, we know that its radius is $a$.

This is the most straightforward solution, however if you insist on parametrization we can be more adventurous. Our goal in the this case is to parametrize the curve $\gamma:$ $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccr}x+y+z&=&0\\x^2+y^2+z^2&=&a^2\\\end{array}\right.$$ Let's take a look at the first equation: $0=x+y+z=\left(x+\frac{z}{2}\right)+\left(y+\frac{z}{2}\right)=u+v$, where $u$ and $v$ are the expressions in the princesses. The first equation transforms into $u+v=0$ (much better). For the equation of the sphere we will get $$a^2=x^2+y^2+z^2=\left(u-\frac{z}{2}\right)^2+\left(v-\frac{z}{2}\right)^2+z^2=u^2+v^2-z(u+v)+\frac{3}{2}z^2$$ We remember that $u+v=0$ and our system is reduced to: $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccr}u+v&=&0\\2u^2+\frac{3}{2}z^2&=&a^2\\\end{array}\right.,\hskip{30pt} \left\{\begin{array}{ccr}u+v&=&0\\\frac{u^2}{a^2/2}+\frac{z^2}{2/3a^2}&=&1\\\end{array}\right. $$
Now we apply the standard parameter for an ellipse $$\begin{array}{rcl}u&=&\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t\\z&=&\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}a\sin t\\v&=&-u\\\end{array}$$ We should not  forget to bring these equation to the original system of coordinates $$\begin{array}{rcl}x(t)&=&u-\frac{1}{2}z=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t-\frac{a}{\sqrt{6}}\sin t, \\y(t)&=&v-\frac{1}{2}z=-\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t-\frac{a}{\sqrt{6}}\sin t, \\z(t)&=&\frac{2a}{\sqrt{6}}\sin t,\end{array}$$ where $0\le t \le2\pi$. For sake of completeness let us compute the form $ydx+zdy+xdz$ in terms of the parameter $t$. We keep thorough track of the terms $\sin^2t$ and $\cos^2t$ and we don't care much about the terms of the form $\sin t\cos t$ since the integration of the mixed terms over $[0,2\pi]$ will result in $0$: $$ydx+zdy+xdz=\left[C\sin t\cos t-\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{12}}+\frac{2a^2}{\sqrt{12}}\right]dt=\frac{C}{2}\sin2tdt+\frac{a^2}{2\sqrt{3}}dt,$$ where $C$ is an irrelevant constant. After integrating from $0$ to $2\pi$ the first term disappears due to the periodicity and we arrive to $$\mathcal{F}=\frac{a^2}{2\sqrt{3}}\cdot 2\pi=\frac{\pi a^2}{\sqrt{3}},$$ which confirms our earlier computation.

Here again the contour direction was not specified. The change of direction will result in the integration from $2\pi$ to $0$ which will reverse the sign of the integral if necessary.